# Why does my soql return accounts which have no contacts

Tags: apex, soql, account, contact

I have a requirement where I need to soql contacts from account I wrote an soql which should only return account with contacts. Instead I also get accounts without contacts, why?:

```
[SELECT id, Name, (SELECT id,lastname,firstname FROM Contacts WHERE lastname  LIKE '%b%') 
 FROM Account 
 WHERE id IN (Select AccountId from contact WHERE Contact.Id != null)
 LIMIT 20]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your filter criteria is not the same as the sub-query filters. As such, there *are* contacts on those accounts, but none that match your criteria. Try this instead:

```
SELECT id,Name,
    (SELECT id,lastname,firstname FROM Contacts WHERE lastname  LIKE '%b%') 
FROM Account 
WHERE id IN (Select AccountId from contact WHERE lastname  LIKE '%b%')
Limit 20
```

Comment: Thanks that worked!!! This gave me a better understanding of SOQL you are really helpfull as always!!.  If you have the time could you have a look at https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/190652/hot-do-i-fetch-correct-id-from-contact-rows-after-edit-and-save-record